# Parsing CSV Files

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, bioinformatics

I'm a novice with d3.js. All I wanna do is just display functional categorization results in my partition map ([just like this](http://bl.ocks.org/metmajer/5480307)).

The ideal situation is displayed `category` in the **innermost circle**; besides, `gene full names` was presented in the **outermost circle**.

Currently, I have a set of data in CSV format. The next step is converted it to JSON format.

Given data format ([VFs.csv](http://bioinfo.cs.ccu.edu.tw/biostars_YT/VFs.csv)):

```
Name,Category
CT396,"Adherence"
htpB,"Adherence"
msbA,"Adherence"
rfaE,"Adherence"
flgK,"Motility"
flhA,"Motility"
fliF,"Motility"
...
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
d3.csv("VFs.csv", function(d) {
    return {
        gene : d.Name,
        Category : d.Category,
        time : 1
    };
});
```

Required format for D3 partition plugin:

```
var data = {
        "data": [{
        "Category": "Adherence",
            "data": [{
            "gene": "CT396",
            "time": 1
        }, {
            "gene": "htpB",
            "time": 1
        }, {
            "gene": "msbA",
            "time": 1
        }, {
            "gene": "rfaE",
            "time": 1
        }]
    }, {
        "Category": "Motility",
            "data": [{
            "gene": "flgK",
            "time": 1
        }, {
            "gene": "flhA",
            "time": 1
        }, {
            "gene": "fliF",
            "time": 1
        }]
    }]
};
```

Here is what I have so far. ([Demo Link](http://bioinfo.cs.ccu.edu.tw/Crab/Parsing.php))

The JSON input is **created manually** but I have no idea how to build hierarchical JSON object from CSV format.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: *"D3's JSON format"*... that simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this easily using [d3.nest](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nests).

However, since you want those property names in your desired outcome, you can create your data array using a combination of `forEach`, `filter` and `map`.

Here is a demo. The outcome in the console.log corresponds to your `data.data` array:

```js
var csv = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

var data = [];
[...new Set(csv.map(d => d.Category))].forEach(d => {
  data.push({
    Category: d,
    data: csv.filter(e => e.Category === d).map(f =>
      ({
        gene: f.Name,
        time: 1
      }))
  });
})

console.log(data)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">Name,Category
CT396,"Adherence"
htpB,"Adherence"
msbA,"Adherence"
rfaE,"Adherence"
flgK,"Motility"
flhA,"Motility"
fliF,"Motility"</pre>
```

PS: I'm using a `<pre>` element to store your CSV.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What information is hidden here? `[...new`

Comment: There is no information hidden anywhere. This is a way to get the unique values in an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0):

try this one 
var data = [];

```
 d3.csv("VFs.csv", function(d) {
    data.push({
      Category: d.Category,
      data: [{
        gene: d.gen,
        time: 1
      }]
    })
 })
```